# How to get notified when an event triggers on ethereum smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

When someone makes a transfer from my account, an event gets trigger name

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint to)
```

Now I want to get notified when this event occurs on smart contract. I tried with difference things like filter, watch, subscription and etc. But nothing works as per need.

I also have an another query
What does filter, subscribe, and watch exactly do. I am always getting confuse between these terms. Can someone give a clear idea.

***Note: I am using WEB3JS 1.0.0.26 version.***

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example for `web3js 1.0.0.beta*`:

```
function handler (event) {
   console.log(event.returnValues);
}

function errorCallback (err) {
   console.error(err);
}

let subscription = contractObj.events.TestEvent().subscription;
subscription.on('data', handler).on('error', errorCallback);
```

To unsubscribe:

```
subscription.unsubscribe(function (result) {
   console.log(result)
});
```

Example of usage in class:

```
class Listener {
  constructor(event, handler) {
    this.subscription = event;
    this.subscription.on('data', handler).on('error', this.errorCallback);
  }

  errorCallback(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}


class Test {
  constructor(contractObj) {
    this.contractObj = contractObj;
    this.createListener();
  }

  createListener() {
    let self = this;
    this.listener = new Listener(this.contractObj.events.TestEvent(), function (event) {
      self.returnValues = event.returnValues;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working. subscription is getting undefined @Dmitry

Comment: Works fine for me on `1.0.0-beta.27` @Harsh

Comment: let subscription = contractObj.events.TestEvent().subscription;

Your this line is getting undefined.
Till contractObj.events.TestEvent() I am getting a Subscription{} 

but when I execute this line 
contractObj.events.TestEvent().subscription;

its getting undefined. Even I changed from subscription to Subscription but it didn't worked

Comment: Are contract inited like that `let contractObj  = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress)` and have TestEvent declared in ABI? @Harsh

Comment: I have looked and yes I have Transfer event in events section and also I have initialise ContractObj the same way you have written above.

Comment: I have heard that subscription do not work in http server.

they work either in IPC or websocket. Do you know how to set IPC or websocket provider for web3

I tried with web3.setProvider with WS and IPC but its not working. I have created a local node in my VPS server

Comment: @Harsh Yes, subscriptions don't work with HTTP providers. In order to WS provider to work, you should enable WS RPC endpoint on your local node and init web3 with WS provider: `const web3SocketProvider = new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://0.0.0.0:8546');` then `const myWeb3 = new Web3(web3SocketProvider);`

Comment: How to set this address "ws://0.0.0.0:8546". If I have created a ethereum geth server on node and I am accessing it using SSH

Comment: [program:geth]
command=/usr/bin/geth --fast --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpcport 8545 --ws --wsport 8546 --wsaddr 127.0.0.1 --wsorigins * --wsapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,ssh,txpool,personal,web3 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/geth.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/geth.out.log


is configuration I made for geth

Comment: @Harsh You set it in options `wsaddr` and `wsport` in geth config. btw - 8546 is the default port for WebSocket provider, so you could omit this option. Do you have an access to the ws port? Try `telnet /node_ip/ 8546` to figure it out.